# Makefile SHELL= weirdness

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile I have:

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/time -f "$@ total time: %E" /bin/sh
```

which works fine on one of my linux boxes. However, on another box it make segfaults. If I remove that line it's fine. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that

1. "$@" is expanded as expected
2. /usr/bin/time works good
3. look in the man time on the target machine, to see whether that version of time recognizes "%E"

Comment: the $@ is not expanding properly in the quotes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you cannot. That is expanded by the shell... You need another shell .